# Should it be "You left a fingerprint (or) finger mark on the TV screen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

One of the problems is that my children sometimes touch my TV screen, which leave dirty blurry marks on the screen.

I am not sure if we can say "*You left a fingerprint on the TV screen*".

"*Fingerprint*" sounds like it is used for the police or in crime investigation.

Is it correct to say "***You left a fingerprint** on the TV screen*" or "***You left a finger mark** on the TV screen*"?

Comment: I don’t think this is _actually_ observed as a significant difference in practice, but if I were to describe the difference between the two here, I would say that _fingerprints_ would imply exactly the type that the police use, where the finger was stationary when pressed against the screen, so that the individual lines in the pattern are visible. _Fingermarks_ would be more likely to be smudged, as by a finger being drawn across the screen.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that was exactly my thinking too. Perhaps you could post it as an answer.

Comment: *"One of the problems is that my children sometimes touch my TV screen"* - That's why they invented tasers

Comment: "You've left your grubby fingerprints all over the telly!"

Comment: Yet another "what the heck is a finger mark? comment.  In the USA, fingerprints are definitely *not* just for the police.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a child to leave just a single *fingerprint* or *[fingermark](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fingermark)* (one word) on a screen would be barely noticeable. I think the plural form is preferable:

> “You left **fingermarks** on the TV screen”
> “Oh dear, there are **fingerprints** all over the TV screen”

UPDATE
I'm a bit surprised by the number of supported comments that express skepticism on the meaning/usage of the term *fingermark*.

> 1. *I'd never even heard of the phrase "finger mark" until I watched the TV series Murdoch Mysteries. To me (native American English speaker) that sounds as outdated and antiquated as the TV show seemed to imply it to be* @Freeman
> 2. I've only ever heard "you left fingerprints" or "you left marks/smudges/scratches" - "finger marks" sounds very odd to me. @Owen Reynolds
> 3. *… Fingermarks would be more likely to be smudged, as by a finger being drawn across the screen*. @JanusBahsJacquet

For the doubters here is the definition of *fingermark* by Cambridge Dictionary. [Emphasis in bold mine]

> **a mark left by dirt or oil from someone's finger on a clean surface**:
>
> - *He'd left sticky fingermarks all over the glass.*

The following images are taken from a forensic science volume; *[Fingerprints and Other Ridge Skin Impressions](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Fingerprints_and_Other_Ridge_Skin_Impres/2gdEDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fingermarks%20on%20the%20glass&pg=PT307&printsec=frontcover)*

[image: magnified image of a fingermark on glass]

> 4.1 Example of a visible negative fingermark on glass

[image: magnified image of two distinct fingermarks]

> 4.6 Three-year-old fingermarks on a glass microscope slide developed by vacuum metal deposition.

Fingermarks needn't be smudgy or appear smeared, they can be as distinct and as identifiable as fingerprints taken by the police or used in a biometric passport.

Comment: *Fingermark* doesn’t sound correct to me (AmE native speaker). Wonder which regions use it.

Comment: Fingermark is not a common word in British English. An anglophone would know what it means (it's a mark from a finger, duh) but they wouldn't call it this.

Comment: "Fingermark" is certainly a real word, but Google Ngram Viewer shows that "fingerprint" is overwhelmingly more common—about 40 times as common, to be precise. Before about 2010, "fingerprint" was over 500 times as common as "fingermark."

Comment: Note that I only said that _fingermark_ would be more likely to be applied to smudgy or smeared marks than _fingerprint_. That is, the term _fingerprint_ has become so closely associated with police/crime shows (where by necessity they are of the clear type) that people would be less likely to use it to refer to drawn out grubby fingers drawn across the screen (such as the four long stripes in [this image](http://stereobarn.com/wp-content/uploads/screen-kleen-hand-smear-fingerprints-on-hdtv.jpg) – at least, I’d call those fingermarks, but I (probably) wouldn’t call them fingerprints.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Meanwhile I would call those *four long stripes* “streaks”, “greasy smears” or “smudges” rather than “fingerprints” or “fingermarks”. Interestingly, the description of the image says "…hand-smear-fingerprints-on-hdtv" So someone thought that the term "fingerprints" was appropriate. That a user prefers one term over the other is fine, that one term is more popular is also fine with me. But when a speaker/user disbelieves hard evidence and insists that only one term is correct, then the only thing left for me to do is use one of my favourite Italian gestures   !

Comment: Oh absolutely – I just wanted to point out that I _didn’t_ disbelieve it, my comment under the question was just to add extra details about how the use of the two terms would be likely to be applied. I find ‘fingermarks’ to be perfectly natural and idiomatic.

Comment: While I appreciate the references to forensics literature in support of the existence of "fingermark" (also never heard of it), I am not sure these references support its use outside of field-specific jargon.

Comment: Meanwhile two answers that are not explicitly negating the meaning or usage of finger marks or fingermarks, are conveniently ignored. It is possible to use fingermarks outside forensic science, please see Cambridge definition linked above and Collins https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finger-mark (origin 1830-40)

Answer (score 16):

I would absolutely prefer "You left a fingerprint on the TV screen". Fingerprint is still used informally for any smudge your finger leaves, from a cell phone screen to white linen.

To me, "finger mark" is an awkward phrase especially when it's singular. If you did want to use "mark", alternates would be "You left finger marks on the TV" or "Your finger left marks on the TV", even if there was only one mark, in my opinion.

This extends to other body parts as well, such as leaving a "butt print" on a leather chair or a "nose print" on a window when leaning in to look too closely.

Comment: I'd never even heard of the phrase "finger mark" until I watched the TV series _Murdoch Mysteries_. To me (native American English speaker) that sounds as outdated and antiquated as the TV show seemed to imply it to be.

Answer (score 10):

Both are fine.  Fingerprints refer to both the deliberate impressions made by police with ink, and to the accidental marks made on smooth surfaces by skin oils and moisture.

> Moisture and grease on a finger result in fingerprints on surfaces such as glass or metal.  (Wikipedia)

But "finger marks" is also fine, especially in the context you propose.

Comment: cf “footprint”, which also could be either a well defined print used in forensics, or smudged muddy marks left in a recently cleaned floor.

Comment: I'm curious -- "finger mark" seems fine and I understand what it's supposed to mean, but I've never heard anyone say or write it in any context, ever. Have you?

Comment: I've only ever heard "you left fingerprints" or "you left marks/smudges/scratches" - "finger marks" sounds very odd to me.

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic thing to say would be "smudge", unless you really wanted to emphasize that it came from their finger, in which case you can say "Your finger left a smudge".